# Windows 8 Console task Command window

Tags: windows-8, scheduled-tasks, console-application, command-window

I have task setup in Windows 8 that runs after every 5 mins. This is a console exe file which shows Command window if run manually but it also shows command window ever 5 mins when it runs through task scheduler. Is there any setting on Windows 8 which I am not aware to hide the command window. It never happened in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution. Changed the User group to System and Checked the checkbox which says to Run task with highest privileges.